# Adding buttons to Add New Post and Add New Page

Tags: posts, customization, pages, hooks, actions

I want to add a button in Add New Page and Add New Post pages.

Here are places I want to add items:

- New page's sidebar (next to Page Attributes).
- New post's sidebar (next to Post Attributes).
- New page's top bar (next to Block Navigation).
- New post's sidebar (next to Block Navigation).

What are the action hook to do it so?

```
function add_new_button_function (???)
{
    echo "some html code";
}

add_action( '???', 'add_new_button_function' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

Here is a [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/plugin-sidebar-0/) for adding Custom sidebar. You can check possibilities and sample codes to add new metaboxes or buttons.